# How can nft block excessive 443 access?

Tags: linux, firewall, ddos, nftables, syn

I'm having a hard time configuring `nft` to fight floods on 443/TCP.

I gave up on `iptables` and module `recent`, and now I'm testing `nft` with its man page sample code, as a lab.

So, I'm sending all source IPs with `syn` flag and `sport 443` when it occurs over 300 times/second to a dynamic set, for 15 minutes. At the same time, I'm checking inbound IPs with `tcpdump`, but the IPs included in the set are not shown by `tcpdump`!

This is how the set "denylist" has been defined:

```
$ sudo nft add rule ip filter INPUT ip protocol tcp tcp flags syn tcp dport https limit rate over 300/minute add @denylist { ip saddr }
```

The nft rule is:

```
$ sudo nft add rule ip filter INPUT ip protocol tcp tcp flags syn tcp dport https limit rate over 300/minute add @denylist { ip saddr }
```

I'm watching the traffic with tcpdump:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -ni any "tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-syn and src host ($IP)"
```

`$IP` is any of the IPs inserted in the set `@denylist`.

What am I doing wrong?

#nft #firewall #linux #synflood

Comment: You're showing 2 lines of your firewall rules. Please provide all of them: `nft list ruleset`. That's probably the whole rathan than the part that is wrong.